# Can VirtualBox VBoxManage add/remove shared folders on the fly?

Tags: virtualbox, docker-machine

When I am trying to add/remove shared folder to my VirtualBox I am getting this error:

```
~$ VBoxManage sharedfolder add dev --name srv --hostpath  "/my/local/path"

VBoxManage: error: The machine 'dev' is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 1012 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

It works when I stop the machine, manipulate shares and then start the machine again. It also works from the VirtualBox UI but I would like to script these operations.

Running VirtualBox 5.0.12 on Mac OS Yosemite. The box was provisioned with `docker-machine`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by 'socratis' at [Virtual Box Forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=75474&p=351510#p351510), the way to do this is by using the `--transient` flag:

```
     ~$ VBoxManage sharedfolder add dev --name srv --hostpath  "/my/local/path" --transient
```

When using `--transient`, the mapping will not persist over the VM restart.

The [VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) mentions this as well:

> There are two types of shares:
>
> VM shares which are only available to the VM for which they have been defined;
>   transient VM shares, which can be added and removed at runtime and do not persist after a VM has stopped; for these, add the --transient option to the above command line.

Comment: Yes, but I want the shared folder to be permanent, not transient. You can do this with VirtualBox GUI (add permanent shared folder while VM is running), so it should be able to done via command line as well.

Comment: To make them permanent you will need to stop the box, make changes and then start the box. I know of no other way. As a matter of fact, using VirtualBox directly turned out to be too cumbersome and I have switched to Vagrant

Comment: How to set the mount-point for a shared-folder by command line?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can add shared folder with VboxManage command but this changes are not permanent

Note: To enable folder sharing with vBOX you will have to install install Vbox-guest driver on your guest machine, then only you can share hosts folder inside your guest vm

Comment: For more details, please refer below Link https://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/VirtualBox_Shared_Folders