VS Code - Python - ModuleNotFoundError
I am running into problems when executing python modules from within a virtual environment using Python and am praying that someone out there is able to help!
The issue I appear to be having is that VS Code is not looking for any libraries installed within my .venv directory path, as the python module runs without errors when run using the cmd within the Terminal window.
I think there may be an issue with my vs code settings.
Here are the steps I have already tried:

uninstalled and reinstalled both Python and VS Code
created a new virtual environment and selected the Python Interpreter for the .venv virtual environment.
activated the .venv environment using cmd in my terminal
installed the pandas module (also uninstalled and re-installed multiple times)
confirmed pandas is available within .venv
Executed my code successfully in the Terminal window using cmd

I have Python 3.12.3 installed and the latest version of VS Code, on my Windows machine.
I have created a test.py file which has some basic code for testing which includes sys.path information, which is shown below:
def main():
  myvar = "hello"
  print(myvar)
  return

main()


import sys
print(sys.path)

import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)

I have include the output I get when running the python script in VS Code (after selecting the .venv python interpreter below:
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\hemal\my_projects\test.py"
hello
['c:\\Users\\hemal\\my_projects', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hemal\my_projects\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.154 seconds

The output using cmd from my terminal window is shown below:
(.venv) C:\Users\hemal\my_projects>python test.py   
hello
['C:\\Users\\hemal\\my_projects', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\my_projects\\.venv', 'C:\\Users\\hemal\\my_projects\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages']
2.2.2

(.venv) C:\Users\hemal\my_projects>

Looking over the output from both methods of running the code, it appears that when I run my test.py module using VS Code, it is not pointing to the .venv environment.
Here is a list of the libraries installed on my virtual environment, taken using pip freeze:

(.venv) C:\Users\hemal\my_projects>pip freeze
cachetools==5.3.3
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
google-auth==2.29.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.0
gspread==6.1.2
idna==3.7
numpy==1.26.4
oauthlib==3.2.2
pandas==2.2.2
pyasn1==0.6.0
pyasn1_modules==0.4.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.1
requests==2.32.2
requests-oauthlib==2.0.0
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1

(.venv) C:\Users\hemal\my_projects>

This is the first time posting on here, so I hope the above is legible and makes sense?!?
Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you!

Does this answer your question? How can I set up a virtual environment for Python in Visual Studio Code?

i know some would consider this bad practice, but i avoid virtual environments for those reasons. i find them rather annoying and it is much better practice (and easier) to keep an updated requirements.txt file.

@thom747 - thank you for sharing the link.  I referenced the information on setting up virtual environments (along with some videos, too). The issue still persisted.  I also looked into making the changes to the .json file.  Unfortunately, I hit a dead end on that front.  It looks like there may have been some updates in vs code based on this document - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Setting-descriptions#pythondefaultinterpreterpath.  Could this be the reason why when I run the module using the IDE it defaults to the global interpreter, even though I select the venv python?

@D.L - I think I may have to go down an alternative path such as the one you have suggested.  I am fairly new to using vs code and I have been endlessly going around in circles for a few days already :/ .  Am I right in assuming that by using the requirements.txt file, anytime I run a module or package I would be using the global python interpreter and it would import the files each time I run my code?  If you have any links to resources on this approach, I would greatly them.  Thanks

@HemalDavda,  not quite, but when you are ready to export the module into production you then have a list of the required files for installation. if you wanted to guarantee a separate space, then you could use docker or back to venv.

this is quite a cool answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974960/whats-the-difference-between-docker-and-python-virtualenv

@D.L - I appreciate you sharing these resources.  It looks like the issue I am having is due to the code runner extension I have installed.  After uninstalling code runner my python script is able to import the modules my venv and executes without any errors.  I tried configuring the settings in code runner before removing it, however I wasn't confident in going down this path as I wasn't sure if this would create issues further down the road.  So for now, I will work without this extension.  Thanks again for your support!
