# Vagrat Box vs docker?

Tags: docker, vagrant, containers, virtual-machine

**Vagrant Box:**

Boxes are the package format for Vagrant environments. A box can be used by anyone on any platform that Vagrant supports to bring up an identical working environment.

**Docker**

Docker is a tool that packages, provisions and runs containers independent of the OS. A container packages the application service or function with all of the libraries, configuration files, dependencies and other necessary parts to operate

Question :

How docker and vagrant box are different from each other?

What freedom does they provide for the developer and production?

How Developer can make use of the Vagrant and differenciate the differences between docker and vagrant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use Vagrant or Docker for creating an isolated environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647069/should-i-use-vagrant-or-docker-for-creating-an-isolated-environment)

Answer (score 3):

**Vagrant** : Vagrant is a project that helps the spawning of virtual machines. It started as an command line of VirtualBox, something similar to Gemfile for VM's. You can choose the base image to start with, network, IP, share folders and put it all in a file that anyone can reuse to spawn the same configured machine. Vagrant has different extensions, provisioning options and VM providers. You can run a VirtualBox, VMware and it is extensible enough to be able to create instances on EC2.

**Docker** : Docker, allows to package an application with all of its dependencies into a standardized unit of software development. So, it reduces a friction between developer, QA and testing. The idea is to share the linux kernel. It dynamically change your application, adding new capabilities every single day, scaling out services to quickly changing the problem areas. Docker is putting itself in an excited place as the interface to PaaS be it networking, discovery and service discovery with applications not having to care about underlying infrastructure. The industry now benefits from a standardized container work-flow and an ecosystem of helpful tools, services and vibrant community around it.

Following are few points ease for developer and production deployments:

ACCELERATE DEVELOPERS : Your development environment is the first and foremost thing in IT. Whatever you want, the different tools, databases, instances, networks, etc. you can easily create all these with docker using simple commands(Image creation using Dockerfile or pull from Docker Hub). Get 0 to 100 with docker machine within seconds and as a developer I can focus more on my application.

EMPOWER CREATIVITY : The loosely coupled architecture where every instance i.e. container here is completely isolated with each other. So, their is no any conflict between the tools, softwares, etc. So, the more creative way developer can utilize the system.

ELIMINATE ENVIRONMENT INCONSISTENCIES : Docker containers are responsible for actual running of the applications and includes the operating system, user-files and metadata. And docker image is same across the environment so your build will go seamlessly from dev to qa, staging and production.

In production environment you must have a zero downtime along with automated deployments. You should take care of all things as service discovery, logging and monitoring, scaling and vulnerability scanning for docker images, etc. All these things accelerate the deployment process and help you better serve the production environment. You don't need to login into production server for any configuration change, logging or monitoring. Docker will do it for you. Developers must understand that docker is a tool, it's nothing without other components. But, it will definitely reduce your huge deployment from hours to minutes. Hope this will clear. Thank you.

Comment: How this provide the usability for developer and production deployments. Can please eloborate further for prod usage

Comment: @JinnaBalu: Added short description hope it will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Docker relies on containerization, while Vagrant utilizes virtualization.