# Docker-machine vs Vagrant?

Tags: docker, vagrant, docker-machine

I am reading about docker-machine and Vagrant. From what I am reading its looks like docker-machine is light version of Vagrant, but Vagrant gives you more flexibility and control. Am I right?

Today I am using docker on my local machine with MacOS. I use Docker for simple stuff like run database server and etc. So Docker is great to have in many ways.

But if I want to seperate my dev environments?

Can anyone who have experience with both tell me which one I should prefer if I want to seperate my dev environments and pros/cons with both?

I want to understand which one I should use, docker-machine or Vagrant?

Thank you for helping me understand pros/cons with both and concept of it :)

Comment: Completely different things. Vagrant isn't popular any more. Use docker. Docker machine is old-tech that isn't maintained any more. Vagrant is, but it's for VM development, not containers.

Comment: Hope this helps. [Should I use vagrant or docker for creating an isolated environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647069/should-i-use-vagrant-or-docker-for-creating-an-isolated-environment)

Comment: docker is a trending technology, If you use vagrant, It will take some fixed amount of memory and storage from your hosts.

Docker containers run as isolated processes in the host operating system. whereas Vagrant has a completely separate instance of the operating system running each time, it has the highest level of isolation available without using separate hardware.

read this: https://www.sumologic.com/blog/vagrant-vs-docker/